# compute sum dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I have two textboxes `Num1` and `Num2` and another textbox `Sum` having the value `10`.

How can I do this wherein if the user will enter a number for `Num1`, it will add it to `Sum` and dynamically change the displayed number in the `Sum` textbox. If the user will enter a number in `Num2` it will also add that number to the updated number shown in `Sum` textbox and dynamically change the value for `Sum` textbox also.

How to do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 4):

Something like that:

```
<input type="text" id="Num1" value="1" onblur="recalculateSum();"/>
<span>+</span>
<input type="text" id="Num2" value="1" onblur="recalculateSum();"/>
<span>=</span>
<input type="text" id="Sum" value=""/>
<script>

    function recalculateSum()
    {
        var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Num1").value);
        var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Num2").value);
        document.getElementById("Sum").value = num1 + num2;

    }

</script>
```

Comment: theres a problem because when I use '+' it will concatenate.

Answer (score 4):

Another version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Summer</title>
</head>
<body>
  Num 1: <input type="text" id="num1" name="num1" value="4"/><br />
  Num 2: <input type="text" id="num2" name="num2" value="6"/><br />
  Sum    <input type="text" id="sum"  name="sum" value="10">

<script type="text/javascript">
  var _num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
  var _num2 = document.getElementById('num2');
  var _sum  = document.getElementById('sum');

  _num1.onblur = function(){
    _sum.value = (parseInt(_sum.value,10) + parseInt(this.value,10));
  };
  _num2.onblur = function(){
    _sum.value = (parseInt(_sum.value,10) + parseInt(this.value,10));
  };  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @ScottSEA. Though after reading the comments from maerics and Robusto, I went with the onblur event instead since onchange won't update sum if the same number is entered into the input field. :)

Comment: this gives me cumulative sum... For example, if I change the first field from 4 to 3, I get 13 instead of 9 (previous sum 10 + new number 3).  Is that intentional?

Comment: nevermind, I get it.  For simply the sum of the two numbers, functions need to be replaced with: _sum.value = (parseInt(_num1.value,10) + parseInt(_num2.value,10));

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" id="Num1" name="Num1"/>
<input type="text" id="Num2" name="Num2"/>
<input type="text" id="Sum" name="Sum"/>


function addNums() {
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Num1').value,10);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Num2').value,10)
  document.getElementById('Sum').value = (num1 + num2).toString();
}
```

There are other ways to reference the form items, but this one works.

Comment: If the "addNums" function is called repeatedly, say with `setInterval`, then the sum can update regularly.  This is better than depending on the "onchange" handler of input elements, which can fire at unexpected times for the user (e.g. after focus is changed, instead of when the user "finishes" typing).

Comment: @maerics: I think you meant this comment for @jtp's response. He's the one talking about onchange handlers. The scope of my reply had nothing to do with when the function gets called, it merely illustrated the mechanics of adding numerical values in input elements.

Comment: @maerics - Good point for onchange event. Even with its browser quirks, it is technically a semantic error in this case since inputting the same value will not update sum.

Comment: sorry my comment was confusing, I was trying to explain how your mechanics could be combined with a trigger that makes it more robust than a solution that uses "onchange" handlers. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" id="Num1" value="1" onblur="recalculateSum();"/>

<input type="text" id="Num2" value="1" onblur="recalculateSum();"/>

<input type="text" id="Sum" value=""/>
<script>

    function recalculateSum()
    {
        var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Num1").value);
        var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Num2").value);
        document.getElementById("Sum").value = num1 + num2;

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function calculate(){
    var x=parseInt(document.getElementById("first").value);
    var y=parseInt(document.getElementById("second").value);
    document.getElementById("answer").value=(x+y);
    }
    </script>

    <title>exam</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        First:<input id="first" name="first" type="text"><br>
        Second:<input id="second" name="second" type="text"><br>
        Answer:<input id="answer" name="answer" type="text"><br>
        <input onclick="calculate()" type="button" value="Addition">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```