# How to print the result to a text box in php

Tags: php

I have 3 text box in the form.. in textbox1 i put one value and in the next textbox put another value and after clicking the third textbox the result will print on it.without button click

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: What is the result you want in the 3rd text box? Is it summing up first 2? Concatenate first 2?

Please be more specific!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please visit this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Say you have this, then:

```
<input type="text" name="txt1" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="txt2" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="txt3" value=""/>
```

You'd echo your PHP variables like this:

```
<input type="text" name="txt1" value="<?= $var1 ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="txt2" value="<?= $var2 ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="txt3" value="<?= $var3 ?>"/>
```

That's how you output php variables directly, if that's what you're looking for.

If you want to have immediate result on the 3rd textbox based on the values of the 1st and 2nd textboxes, you'd need a javascript solution, or ajax. PHP doesn't run after the page is loaded, unless you call it assincronously (AJAX).

If you're looking for a javascript answer, [this could help.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029859/4802649)